# Youtube video won't play: An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: iSS5074BR2g5VT97)

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I have some youtube videos embedded in my webpage. They display fine, but when I click on them, they wont play, just display the error above.

Here's my code:
'''

```
<div class="music-videos">
    <iframe class="music-video" width="575" height="425"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=zM32nQ21O9E">
    </iframe>
    
    <iframe class="music-video" width="575" height="425"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=Jbg5BXUlXrs">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

'''

Comment: Try with,

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zM32nQ21O9E"` and `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jbg5BXUlXrs"`

Comment: I tried getting rid of the 'v=' like you said. Now one of the videos works and the other does not. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should be working, maybe you will have to check the URL for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

When the link has the word `embed` on it, the `VIDEO_ID` is separated with a slash `/`.

Hence, you should change your URLs as follows:

> `https://www.youtube.com/embed/zM32nQ21O9E`

Modified code:

```
<div class="music-videos">
    <iframe class="music-video" width="575" height="425"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zM32nQ21O9E">
    </iframe>
    
    <iframe class="music-video" width="575" height="425"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jbg5BXUlXrs">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

If you keep getting errors, please, test this code in another computer or while you're logged out from your account. This error *might* be some undocumented bug or any conflict with your browser add-ons.